# getting bibliography to use numbers as keys

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to get numbers, e.g. [5], as keys in my document when I refer to a publication in my bibliography. Here is the code that I'm using to print all of the references in my database:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{C:/work/papers/database} % References file

\end{document}
```

This produces all authors names as a key.

I am using WinEdt, if that's of any conciliation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.  Actually this code produces numbered citations of the form `[5]`.  May be you are compiling a different document?  Please update your code so it demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems weird that you are getting the names since your are using the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Apa references and mla are authors names or lastnames, plain should be using numbers

Please change the bibliographystyle to ieeetr

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

IEEE asks for numbers as well when using \cite{}